# Como criar um json a partir do meu objeto?

Tags: php, json, método

Tenho um objeto Produto que não consigo transformar em json usando `json_encode`:

```
<?php
class Produto {
    public $nome;
    public $preco;
    public $descricao;

    function transformarJson(){
    }

}

?>
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Como você está usando a função json_encode?

Comment: Putz Yure Pereira ! Muito obrigado pela ajuda ! Estou estudando programação agora, valeu pela força !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso da seguinte forma abaixo, no exemplo estou usando a função nativa do PHP `json_encode` que transforma um objeto para o formato `json`, mas caso você venha querer fazer o inverso, você também pode usar a função `json_decode`:

```
<?php
class Produto {

    public $nome;
    public $preco;
    public $descricao;

    public function transformarJson(){

        return json_encode($this);

    }
    // Não consigo transformar meu objeto Produto em json usando json_encode

}

$produto = new Produto();

$produto->nome = 'Celular';
$produto->preco = 'R$ 1010,00';
$produto->descricao = 'Celular';

var_dump($produto->transformarJson());
```

Resultado:

```
string(46) "{"nome":"Test","preco":"test","descricao":"e"}"
```

[Teste o código aqui](http://ideone.com/avO3Wv)